# How to update value from v-for="(value,key) in obj" in vue-js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i have object with key value pair and I am using for loop on it.

```
     <CCol
            sm="6"
            v-for="(
              my_value, my_key
            ) in my_obj"
            :key="my_key"
          >
            <CInput
              :label="my_key"
              type="text"
              :placeholder="my_value" // I can use my_value as the placeholder
              :v-model="my_value" // but if I use my_value in v-model it gives an error
            />
          </CCol>
```

I am trying to display key as a label and value as the value of textbox and user can be able to update the value.

when I use value in v-model it gives an error "v-model' directives cannot update the iteration variable 'my_value' itself." but I can use it for the display purpose only like placeholder.

I need the value updatable.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the index then you could use  the key to refer to the respective value :

```
  <CCol
            sm="6"
            v-for="(
              my_value, my_key,index
            ) in my_obj"
            :key="my_key"
          >
            <CInput
              :label="my_key"
              type="text"
              :placeholder="my_value" 
              v-model="my_obj[my_key]" 
            />
          </CCol>
```

when you iterate over an object like :

```
user:{
  first_name:'John',
  last_name:'Doe'
  age:25
}
```

the syntax `v-for="(val,index) in user"` will give you the each value and its index, but when you do `v-for="(val,key,index) in user"` this will give you the value, its key and index.

the right binding is `v-model="object[key]"` which could represent `user.age`, the wrong binding is to use `v-model="val"` and `val` in this case is available only in template like `25` or `Doe` which doesn't exist in  script as property

Comment: I think adding `index` is superfluous.  Clarifying about the iteration, if the dummy variable in the loop (`my_value`) is a scalar, it doesn't make sense to bind it as a v-model because modifying a scalar just modifies the passed value (akin to modifying a scalar function parameter, the caller will never see it).